# Проблема компиляции gcc: multiple definition, first defined here

Tags: c, gcc

Имеются файлы вида:
p.h

```
#ifndef P_H 
#define P_H
#include <stdio.h>
void p();
#endif
```

p.c

```
#include "p.h"
void p() { printf("Hello world\n"); }
```

hello.c

```
#include "p.h"
int main()
{
   p();
   return 0;
}
```

При компиляции с опцией оптимизации -o всё нормально:

```
gcc -c hello.c p.c
gcc hello.o p.o -o result
```

Проблемы возникают при компиляции с опциями -o1 -o2 -o3

```
    gcc -c hello.c p.c
    gcc hello.o p.o -o1 result

result: In function `p':
(.text+0x10b): multiple definition of `p'
p.o:p.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
result: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:/build/buildd/glibc-2.21/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/crti.S:80: first defined here
result: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
result: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
result:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
result: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
result: In function `main':
(.text+0xf6): multiple definition of `main'
hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
result: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:/build/buildd/glibc-2.21/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/crti.S:64: first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/crtend.o:(.tm_clone_table+0x0): multiple definition of `__TMC_END__'
result:(.data+0x10): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: ошибка в result(.eh_frame); таблиц .eh_frame_hdr создана не будет.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

С линуксом и gcc не очень хорошо знаком, в чём проблема не пойму.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

`-o имя` - это имя выходного файла,
`-O1` - это опция оптимизации.

Когда Вы делаете

```
gcc src.o -o result
gcc src.o result -O1
```

Вы линкуете файл `src.o` с файлом `result`, который получился на предыдущем шаге.
Естественно у Вас все имена будут продублированы.

Пишите

```
gcc -c -O2 hello.c p.c
gcc -O2 hello.o p.o -o result
```

а лучше используйте какую-нибудь систему сборки, например CMake.

Answer (score 0):

result -- это имя исполнимой программы?

```
gcc hello.o p.o -o1 result
```

тогда исправте на:

```
gcc hello.o p.o -o result -O1
```